# How to enable Non market application in Managed Profile (Android 5.0) programmatically

Tags: android-5.0-lollipop, device-policy-manager, android-developer-api

Hello I was checking Android 5.0 samples there was sample BasicManagedProfile. Using that I have created managed profile successfully. But it was managing only Market applications (Downloaded from Google Play) as managed application.
But I tried with custom say it HelloWOrld application that is not available on Market. It gave me the error " *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only system apps can be enabled this way*."

```
 devicePolicyManager.enableSystemApp(
                        BasicDeviceAdminReceiver.getComponentName(activity), packageName);
```

code that i was using to enable application.
Is there any way or API to enable Custom application in Managed Profile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching for many days I found that currently google has not provided any API/ methods to enable non-market application in managed profile.

Answer (score 1):

Managed users cannot install non market apps in Lollipop, programmatically or manually. There's a spammy [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79728) about the manual way.

However, there's a workaround for development/personal use.
Just install your app with `adb install` **after** the managed user creation. The app will be installed for both users.

Comment: yes hartok found that solution only. Thank you for response :)