# Restriction policies not working for managed profile in Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-managed-profile

I am new to Android for work features.

I have written a sample app to test the restriction features provided to a profile owner. My sample app creates a managed work profile and sets itself as the profile owner.

I tried to apply some restriction policies after that, e.g., `DevicePolicyManager.addUserRestriction(componentName, UserManager.DISALLOW_UNINSTALL_APPS);`

It works and I am unable to uninstall any app from the managed profile. But when I try to apply: `DevicePolicyManager.addUserRestriction(componentName, UserManager.DISALLOW_INSTALL_UNKNOWN_SOURCES);`, 
it seems to be not working.

I couldn't find the default settings app enabled in the profile.
But when I log the apps installed in the managed profile, I can see two setting packages (`com.android.settings` and `com.android.providers.settings`) in the list.

What my understanding from the above API is after applying the restriction, `Setting->security->Unknown Source` switch should be disabled. But I couldn't find any Settings app in the managed profile to verify.

Also, after applying the restriction, I am able to install any apk from `adb` in the managed profile along with the primary user.

Please let me know if i am missing something.

Comment: Did you tried to install an apk from unknown sources??

Comment: Yes i tried to install from adb, its installing.

Comment: Also i observed a new behavior :: that even without setting UserManager.DISALLOW_INSTALL_UNKNOWN_SOURCES restriction i am unable to install  apps from any source except play store. Is there anyway to change this behavior,as enterprise will sometime push app from their store rather using google play store.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable Non market application in Managed Profile (Android 5.0) programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375736/how-to-enable-non-market-application-in-managed-profile-android-5-0-programmat)